# Django: custom button in admin change form return bad url for custom view function

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have problems to link my custom button from change_form.html to my view function.

[pic : admin change form custom button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snkQo.png)

**change_form.html**

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block title %} Send Email  {% endblock %}
{% block content %}

{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'requests_requests_change'  %}
    <div class="submit-row">
                {% csrf_token %}
            <a href="{% url 'requests:send-email' original.pk %}"
                 class="button" style="background-color: #F08000;float: left">Request Subscription
            </a>
    </div>
            {% endif %}
        {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def send_email(request, requests_id):
    return redirect('')  # or whatever to test the url
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'requests'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/send-email/', views.send_email, name='send-email'),
]
```

**main project urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
                  path('', admin.site.urls),  # admin site administration
                  path('requests/', include('requests.urls')),
              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

[pic: error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypw85.png)

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please, consider improving your question with a description of your problem and your expected result... Pics may be good, but a good description is helpful. See: [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution on my own.
The issue was the url inside the template.
Worked with this one:

Template :

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:requests_requests_change' original.pk %}send-email/"
```

And the URL path:

```
path('<int:pk>/change/send-email/', views.send_email, name='send-email')
```